# How do I remove class from previous selection when clicking additional item?

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/freqn/ZHt6V/2/

How do I remove class from previous selection when clicking additonal item in this accordion?  I want the class to be removed from the previous clicked item when the next item is expanded. All other items should turn back to gray when new item is selected. Thank you.

```
(function () {

    $('dd').hide();
    $('dt').click(function(){
        $(this)
            .next()
            .slideToggle(200)
            .siblings('dd')
            .slideUp(200);
        });   

    $('dt').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

    }); 

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/uptownapps/ZHt6V/5/  -- Revision to add collapse functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/uptownapps/ZHt6V/4/

First you can use the same click function to handle all of this. Also, I prefer to use `removeClass` and `addClass` rather than `toggleClass` just because I am able to keep track of what's happening in my head better that way.

```
    (function () {

    $('dt').click(function(){
        $(this) .next()
                .slideToggle(200)
                .siblings('dd')
                .slideUp(200);

        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

})();
```

You'll notice I also removed the `$('dd').hide();` and instead added `display: none;` to the CSS definition for the `dd` element. This will fix the "flash" you see when the page loads before jQuery and your JS has run.

Comment: Thank you. How do I also remove the class when collapsing the same item?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a new JSFiddle to check if `$(this)` is already the selected item.