# Masonry, remove "is_expanded" class when new item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I´m useing a layout like http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout and is wondering if there is a way to  only have one item active at them time. So that when you expand a new item a the one you currently have open goes back to its original form (removes class="is_expanded") . I´ve quite new to programming and don´t really know where to stat to look, tried configuring [How do I remove class from previous selection when clicking additional item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025799/how-do-i-remove-class-from-previous-selection-when-clicking-additional-item) but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classie.toggle( event.target, 'gigante' );
```

That is the part that does the magic - it adds a class 'gigante' which then makes it 4*4 (or whatever)

If you want to make only one be expanded at a time then

```
eventie.bind( container, 'click', function( event ) {
// don't proceed if item was not clicked on
if ( !classie.has( event.target, 'item' ) ) {
return;
}

// change size of item via class
 $('.item').removeClass('gigante'); // add this line
classie.toggle( event.target, 'gigante' );
// trigger layout
msnry.layout();
});
```

What the line I added does is remove all 'gigante' class from the items and then the toggle will add that class to the item again.

`$('.item')` is just a class that every item has.

This answer assumes that only expanded items will be called 'gigante'.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm, and also I think I understand how to add a similar function in the future when needed.

Comment: $( function() {

  var $container = $('.masonry').masonry({
    columnWidth: 130,
    gutter: 5
  });

  $container.on( 'click', '.item-content', function() {
  $('.item').removeClass('is-expanded'); // add this line
    $( this ).parent('.item').toggleClass('is-expanded');
     
     
    $container.masonry();
  });
  
});